# Path slash issue - composer running on win mintty term

Tags: exception, path, windows-7, composer-php, require

I have a complicated setup, where im using `MSYS2` (same as `cygwin`), and I have composer loading from the windows system, its messing up the path when `autoload _real.php` goes to look into the vendors folder.

This is the path, and I belive the source of the error is directly related to the path being backslash, then forward slash.

```
Fatal error: composerRequire13a8867c9869fbff9e601f6ade4acdee(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\xxx\Documents\projects\project1\vendor\composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')
```

`echo $PATH`

```
~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/home/me/bin:/c/Users/me/AppData/Roaming/npm:/cygdrive/c/Users/me/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/PHP/v5.6:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Windows/CCM:/c/Windows/CCM:/c/Windows/CCM:/c/Program Files/Dell/Dell Data Protection/Drivers/TSS/bin:/c/Program Files/Dell/Dell Data Protection/Encryption:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/c/Users/me/AppData/Local/atom/bin:/c/Users/me/AppData/Roaming/npm:/c/Users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/cmd:/c/Users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/mingw64/bin:/c/Users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/usr/bin:/c/Users/me/AppData/Local/ComposerSetup/bin:/c/Users/me/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl

$ which composer
/home/me/bin/composer
```

**Questions:**

- Does anybody know what i can do to get the slashes corrected?
- Might the overlapping composers in my path be the issue, or is the system just looking at the last one?

---

*Incase anybody wants to see what autoload_real.php is actually doing, heres the method.*

```
function composerRequire4eee5c98214f71aca8f1a9103a64ab95($fileIdentifier, $file)
{
    if (empty($GLOBALS['__composer_autoload_files'][$fileIdentifier])) {
        require $file;

        $GLOBALS['__composer_autoload_files'][$fileIdentifier] = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After realizing that it was only happening in one package, I suspected something in the vendors dir itself was corrupt.  I tried deleting the entire vendors dir then running `composer install` again.  It worked that time.

**Solution**

```
rm -r project/vendors
composer install
```